# Adding custom font manually to .docx

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, docx

I need to set up a Word Template for a multi user office with different operating systems (Mac and Windows). Office 2016 for Mac does not offer the possibility to embed fonts into the .docx container.

Can I add somehow my custom fonts to the container manually? I have created a test file and decompressed it thus I see the actual XML files. I have looked at word/fontTable.xml but it shows only information about used fonts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:fonts xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15">
<w:font w:name="Calibri">
    <w:panose1 w:val="020F0502020204030204"/>
    <w:charset w:val="00"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="E00002FF" w:usb1="4000ACFF" w:usb2="00000001" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0000019F" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="DengXian">
    <w:panose1 w:val="02010600030101010101"/>
    <w:charset w:val="86"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="A00002BF" w:usb1="38CF7CFA" w:usb2="00000016" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0004000F" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="Times New Roman">
    <w:panose1 w:val="02020603050405020304"/>
    <w:charset w:val="00"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="E0002AEF" w:usb1="C0007841" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="Arial">
    <w:panose1 w:val="020B0604020202020204"/>
    <w:charset w:val="00"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="E0002AFF" w:usb1="C0007843" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="DengXian Light">
    <w:panose1 w:val="02010600030101010101"/>
    <w:charset w:val="86"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="A00002BF" w:usb1="38CF7CFA" w:usb2="00000016" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0004000F" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
<w:font w:name="Calibri Light">
    <w:panose1 w:val="020F0302020204030204"/>
    <w:charset w:val="00"/>
    <w:family w:val="auto"/>
    <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
    <w:sig w:usb0="A00002EF" w:usb1="4000207B" w:usb2="00000000" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0000019F" w:csb1="00000000"/>
</w:font>
</w:fonts>
```

I want to include the custom font within the container and use it, so the fonts I included in the template and independent from the machine the template is used on.

Any ideas?